# Rails refactor code for iterating through self-referential structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table of "groups" in a rails project.  Each group can have a parent group, where group_id refers back its own table.

I have this code to iterate through the rows and assemble an array with generations, which works, but I'm thinking there must be a more efficient way to do this, with fewer lines of code, or with only one ActiveRecord lookup, or something just generally simpler... any ideas?

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    root_groups = Group.where 'group_id is null'
    @child_groups = Group.where 'group_id is not null'
    @groups = []

    root_groups.each do |group|
      @groups << [group, 0]
      find_children group, 1
    end
  end

  private

    def find_children (group, generation)
      @child_groups.each do |child|
        if child.group == group
          @groups << [child, generation] 
          find_children child, generation+1
        end
      end
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a [similar situation a few years ago](http://undervale.co.uk/blog/?p=153) and used a join table to manage the relationships. However, I also used collect in my self-referencing method which suggests you should be able to do this:

```
def find_children(group, generation)
  group.collect{|g| [[g, generation] << find_children(g, generation+1)}.uniq
end
```

I'd also suggest you move that logic to the model.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look at [awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) which will do a lot of this work for you